# I need to change the colour of a button in an android widget

Tags: android, button, colors, widget

I have a widget with a button that users must press within a given interval. The button works fine and resets the interval but I want the button to change colour green -> amber -> red depending on time left. I have no problem changing the text on the button using remote views with code like this:

```
RemoteViews views =new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_widget);
views.setCharSequence(R.id.example_widget_button, "setText", buttonText);
```

But I can not make any sort of code change the button colour. I've tried several things along the lines of:

```
views.setCharSequence(R.id.example_widget_button, "setBackgroundTint", "#039be5");
```

I have also tried using a drawable background and changing that. I'm missing something really obvious -it must be possible- I just can't find an example that works in my context.

Can anyone point me?

Comment: Mohammad: Thanks for that - it works and it opens up a bunch of other things I can experiment with. Mehmed: Thanks also - I already have the timer element set up and running, but you have given me food for thought on that too; Runnable and Handler are new to me. I know comments shouldn't be used this way, but I can't up-vote so here it is :O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
views.setInt(R.id.example_widget_button, "setBackgroundColor", android.graphics.Color.BLACK)`;
```

and you change the color to be what you want at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `Handler` or `CountDownTimer`.

If you want to use `Handler`, here is the example:

```java
long totalTime = 10000;
long warningTime = 6000;
long alertTime = 30000;

Runnable warningColorChangeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWarning));
    }
};

Runnable alertColorChangeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAlert));
    }
};

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(warningColorChangeRunnable, totalTime - warningTime);
handler.postDelayed(alertColorChangeRunnable, totalTime - alertTime);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(warningColorChangeRunnable);
        handler.removeCallbacks(alertColorChangeRunnable);
    }
});
```

If you want to use `CountDownTimer`, here is the example:

```java
long totalTime = 10000;
long warningTime = 6000;
long alertTime = 30000;
long interval = 1000;

CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(totalTime, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if (millisUntilFinished <= warningTime && millisUntilFinished > warningTime - interval) {
            button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWarning));
        }
        if (millisUntilFinished <= alertTime && millisUntilFinished > alertTime - interval) {
            button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAlert));
        }
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // Maybe show a failure dialog
    }
}.start();

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
});
```